# Grouping all rows by common userid or transactionid when both may change

Tags: sql, presto

The context is that we have a userid and a transactionid, but sometimes the userid changes but the transactionid stays the same (when both should be constant), due to client settings, and sometimes the transactionid changes but the userid doesn't (so we can't just use the transactionid).

So we want to get something we can use as the actual ID. The new column (i.e. the actual ID) is just used to group the rows, so it can be any arbitrary (unique) value. The ordering doesn't matter at all.

Example:

```
| userid | transactionid |
|--------|---------------|
| A      |             1 |
| A      |             2 |
| A      |             3 |
| B      |             2 |
| B      |             2 |
| C      |             4 |
| D      |             5 |
| D      |             5 |
| D      |             6 |
| E      |             6 |
| E      |             7 |
| F      |             4 |
```

Could become:

```
| userid | transactionid | actualid |
|--------|---------------|----------|
| A      | 1             | A        |
| A      | 2             | A        |
| A      | 3             | A        |
| B      | 2             | A        |
| B      | 2             | A        |
| C      | 4             | C        |
| D      | 5             | E        |
| D      | 5             | E        |
| D      | 6             | E        |
| E      | 6             | E        |
| E      | 7             | E        |
| F      | 4             | C        |
```

We are using Presto so there are some restrictions (no temporary tables, no DISTINCT in aggregate queries, etc. )

A solution using for-loops in Python is shown here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/jamesmcm/2554d5d4498b5d46d42d/raw/587ff552c34027e85ee199d5d8e5cb192e5550d1/gistfile1.txt

But we need a solution for Presto.

This was originally written up on Gist here: https://gist.github.com/jamesmcm/9b9a559eb9f69405c04a

If you want proper formatting for tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using windows function instead of joins and requires an additional step than what @David suggested.

Using the following example

```
uid | tid
 B  |  2
 B  |  3
 B  |  4
 A  |  3
 E  |  1
```

it's possible to do

```
SELECT 
    *,
    MIN(minuid) OVER (PARTITION BY mintid order by 1) as final_id
FROM(
    SELECT 
        tid,
        uid,
        MIN(uid) OVER (PARTITION BY tid order by 1) as minuid,
        MIN(tid) OVER (PARTITION BY uid order by 1) as mintid
    FROM
        log
)
```

and this should return the correct ids

```
uid | tid | minuid | mintid | final_id
 B  |  2  |   B    |   2    |   A
 B  |  3  |   A    |   2    |   A
 B  |  4  |   B    |   2    |   A
 A  |  3  |   A    |   3    |   A
 E  |  1  |   E    |   1    |   E
```

Answer (score 0):

We start by finding the userid (uid) that is assigned to each transactionid (tid). There are many ways to choose this assignment, but will use the smallest (minimum) userid:

```
SELECT tid, min(uid) xid
FROM log
GROUP BY tid
```

This results in the following assignments:

```
 tid | xid 
-----+-----
   1 | A   
   2 | A   
   3 | A   
   4 | C   
   5 | D   
   6 | D   
   7 | E   
(7 rows)
```

Now that we have the assignments, we can join them to the original table:

```
SELECT a.uid, a.tid, b.xid
FROM log a
JOIN (
  SELECT tid, min(uid) xid
  FROM log
  GROUP BY tid
) b
ON (a.tid = b.tid)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Output:

```
 uid | tid | xid 
-----+-----+-----
 A   |   1 | A   
 A   |   2 | A   
 A   |   3 | A   
 B   |   2 | A   
 B   |   2 | A   
 C   |   4 | C   
 D   |   5 | D   
 D   |   5 | D   
 D   |   6 | D   
 E   |   6 | D   
 E   |   7 | E   
 F   |   4 | C   
(12 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! I'm not sure it would work if there was a lot of recursion (i.e. swapping between the uid changing and tid changing) but luckily we don't have that problem at the moment.

Comment: I think this solution works in this case but is not fully correct,

(I cannot add tables here, see my answer for an example for which this approach is not fully working)